# Quotient C8 by C2 group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I attempt to divide a C8 by C2.

My reasoning: C2 is a normal subgroup of C8. C2 forms 2 cosets: {0,2,4,6} and 1+{0,2,4,6}. C8/C2 isomorphic to C4.

But I know that C2*C4 is an Abelian group. It is not C8.

> Theorem 8.7. Cn*Cm=Cnm if and only if n and m are relatively prime.

2 and 4 are not relatively prime. Their multiplication can not form C8.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: $G/H \times H$ is not in general isomorphic to $G$, as this example illustrates.

Comment: What did you mean by C8?

Comment: @rain1 $C_8$ is the cyclic group of order $8$. The $C$ stands for "cyclic".

Comment: @DietrichBurde so that is an Abelian group then, the comment that C2*C4 is abelien does not imply that it is not C8.

Comment: $C_2\times C_4$ cannot be isomorphic to $C_8$, because it has no element of order $8$, but $C_8$ has one.

Comment: What did you mean with “divide”?